# Woocommerce Shortcode - include product ids - fill rest with random

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using:

```
[products limit="12" columns="4" orderby="rand" ids="15876" class="post-products-end"]
```

To display some products, but I want to specify a few product ids, but have the rest of the 12 randomly filled ... is this possible using the shortcode?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could create your own shortcode e.g. [productsrandom]

The code would be something like this:

```
add_shortcode( 'productsrandom', 'bbloomer_custom_products_shortcode' );

function bbloomer_custom_products_shortcode() {
   $product_ids = array( 15876, 15877, 15878, 15879 ); // MANUAL IDS
   $remaining_product_ids = wc_get_products( 
      'status' => 'publish',
      'exclude' => $product_ids,
      'limit' => 12 - count( $product_ids ),
      'return' => 'ids',
   );
   $all_product_ids = implode( ',', array_merge( $product_ids, $remaining_product_ids ) );
   return do_shortcode( '[products limit="12" columns="4" orderby="rand" ids="' . $all_product_ids . '" class="post-products-end"]' );
}
```

Comment: Thanks - but I get the following error: syntax error, unexpected token "=>", expecting ")" on the line after wc_get_products

Comment: All good - just needed to wrap those in an array()

Comment: Actually, this still doesnt work if I assign 12 items into the manual ids the end result is that it may include some of them but the rest are random

Comment: If you assign up to 11 manual products, does it work? Because if you assign 12 of them, the 'limit' calculation comes at 12 - 12 = 0 so that could make a mess